# UISearchBar and UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an .xib file connected to a ViewController, which is init'ed as the root controller of an instance of UINavigationController in my appDelegate.

In that view, I have a UISearchBar and a UITableView below it.

When the view loads up, there's a navigationBar at the top, followed by a ~20 pixel gap, and then the UISearchBar, and the table beneath it:

[image]

My problem is that when I enter the UISearchBar to type something, the navigation bar disappears (which is fine), but the search box is all screwy:

[image]

I'm pretty new to this (a couple of weeks), so I'm not quite sure what's going on. Can anyone help me shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you pull the search bar into the parent view or into the table view? The search bar should be the header view for the table, and not as a standalone view. If you want it to be standalone anyway, make sure your autoresizing flags are correct (under cmd-3 (size) in the inspector in Interface Builder); the search bar should stick to the top and not be flexible in height.

Comment: I had it pulled into the parent view apparently -- no idea you were supposed to put it into the table view. But the problem is still happening. :(

Comment: What if you want the search bar to be a standalone view?